# How to undo after copying a file in centos

Tags: centos, centos6

I wanted to copy contents of one file to another but by mistake i copied the new file to file having contents. So now file which had data is overwritten and is empty. Is there a way to revert this process back without backup. Any way?

centos 6.4

Comment: You can restore it from your backup.

Comment: Its a image-based backup. Is it possible to extract individual file from it.

Comment: There is little you can do if you specifically say to Linux to overwrite the file ... getting back removed files is "easier".  If you have backups on DO,  backup any data that might have been updated from the last backup, and ask them to put back the backup.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Linux doesn't provides undo feature, as far as data concern which tool do you use to take image based data backup.

Comment: auto backups are taken by digital ocean